# Is there a way to set the default camera direction when a page loads, in a-frame?

Tags: camera, rotation, aframe

By default, when I load a scene, the camera is pointing straight ahead. But I would like it to be pointing slightly upwards.

I tried using the rotation attribute to tilt the camera. At first instance, it works. But when I move the camera back down (to what would be its default position), and try to move to the side then, the camera moves in a strange angle. Not like it would if I loaded the scene with no camera rotation, moved up, and moved back again.

I am using the 1.0.4 version of a-frame, on a desktop, in Firefox, controling the scene with the mouse.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>

<a-scene>

  <a-entity id="rig" rotation="20 0 0">
    <a-entity camera look-controls="reverseMouseDrag: true" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>
  <a-sky src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg/1920px-Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg"></a-sky>

</a-scene>
```

Answer (score -2):

Considering rotating `a-sky` instead or setting the objects scene in the starting configuration you need. Be aware that in VR you won't be able to force the user to look into a specific direction.

Comment: I get the same unwanted behaviour either by rotating the camera, or the a-sky. Setting the scene in the starting configuration I need is difficult since the same equirectangular picture will be used multiple times, in different pages, each having the camera point a different way. I am not worried with VR. This will just be a regular website, with 360 panoramas.