# Updated Question - How to set the correct device camera with ARJS and Aframe?

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I'm using the aframe with ARJS to build an Augmented Reality app. What I'm trying to do is to set the camera to stay fixed with my device camera. when I run my app I see the camera shifted up and left. This causes my AR video to be out of the image tracker area.

This is a question related to my question:
[Is there a way to set the default camera direction when a page loads, in a-frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801250/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-camera-direction-when-a-page-loads-in-a-frame)

Appreciate any help.

**[UPDATE]**

I found out that what is actually happening, is that the Aframe camera is selecting my wide-angle camera (Samsung A51). There is an open [issue on the ARJS](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/issues/303) repository.

If someone knows how to avoid this issue, please leave your anwser.

Comment: I have a guest! It seems that the ARJS is using the wrong camera (the wide camera in my case). You can find this issue here https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/issues/303.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Active Camera
When the active property gets toggled, the component will notify the camera system to change the current camera used by the renderer:

```
var secondCameraEl = document.querySelector('#second-camera');
secondCameraEl.setAttribute('camera', 'active', true);
```

see - https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/camera.html#changing-the-active-camera